# Only check out trunk of a git using SVN?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, github

I'm trying to check out only the trunk / main branch of a github project in Linux, using the following command:

```
svn checkout https://github.com/wiremod/wire-extras.git/trunk
```

However, I get an error stating that the URL doesn't exist. What I don't understand is with several other projects, I can run the following commands and check out only the trunk just fine:

```
svn checkout https://github.com/Aaron113/URS.git/trunk -> works fine
svn checkout https://github.com/Nayruden/Ulysses.git/trunk/ulx -> works fine
```

How can I check out this Git so that I only download the trunk, instead of branches and tags. I've found that the command `git svn clone https://github.com/wiremod/wire-extras/trunk wire-extras` works once, but doesn't function properly when I try to use it a second time. This is important because these repos are frequently updated, and I would like to keep the folders on my servers up to date with the master.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't predict, read [page of project on Github](https://github.com/wiremod/wire-extras/) and try to understand it FULLY!!! - find URLs of this repository.
2. Discover, that Git's and Subveersion URLs (surprise!!!) are *different* and **will newer use Git's URL for accessing repo by SVN-client blindly** in future
3. Paste URL of Subversion root into repobrowser of TortoiseSVN or into `svn ls [-R]` command and get [URL of trunk](https://github.com/wiremod/wire-extras/trunk) and see and try to remember difference between good and malformed URLs

> I've found that the command git svn clone... works once, but doesn't function properly when I try to use it a second time

LOL! You **must** to start [RTFM](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html), dude: clone always used only once **in order to create  clone**, for **syncing existing clone** with upstream use must use **another command**(s)